# Can't make SSL connection with cURL/PHP from local machine, works from web server

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, easyphp

I have been using EasyPHP 5.3.2i on Windows XP for a few years and I like to test my website offline before uploading it to my web server. This has always been fine until now, when I need to incorporate SSL connections as part of its functionality. My code works fine when running on the web server, but when trying to open an SSL connection from my local computer (127.0.0.1 etc.) I get the following:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

It was easy enough to install the certificate on my web server, but placing it in the same directory on my local setup doesn't fix this error. Do I have to install it elsewhere or is there something else preventing my establishing an SSL connection here?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the cURL option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false. This will disable verification of the peer's certificate. However, you only want to use this option on your testing server. You can view the full list of options [here](http://php.net/curl_setopt).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this. I have tried every combination of verify peer/host setting I've found. My hunch is still that there's a problem with the installation of the certificate, since that what fixed it on the web site.